# Using DispatchGroup to communicate between two different classes?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm starting the execution of a task in the main view controller as a child/blackground thread.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
let group = DispatchGroup()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        group.enter()


        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {[unowned self] in
            self.checkFolders()
            sleep(50)
            print("finished sleeping")

            self.group.leave()

            }
```

I want another viewController to block until this child thread finishes it's task.

```
class FirstTableViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let startingPoint = Date()
        MainViewController().group.wait()
        print("\(startingPoint.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1) seconds elapsed")
       dataCells = createArrayData() //create dataObjects





}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be blocking. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show how you segue from `MainViewController` to `FirstTableViewController`?

Comment: Don't misuse `DispatchGroup` to make an asynchronous task synchronous. Learn to understand the pattern of asynchronous data processing. And `[unowned self]` is pointless because GCD closures don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: @CodeDifferent I'm segueing via the IB. Right-click mouse and drag from button to `FirstTableViewController`. Thank you.

Comment: @CodeDifferent However, I enter `FirstTableViewController` via another segue as well, from another screen. Since my first screen isn't too active, I wanted to start the `task` early.